# POST request to Localhost not sending response in NodeJS

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express, post, postman

So recently I was trying to learn NodeJS and was following a blog on it. It helped me built a small node server dealing with exercise tracking.
I was trying to send a POST request to the local server but it ended up giving no response, moreover, it was stuck in "Sending Response".

The **server.js** code:

```
const express = require('express'); // Web framework
const cors = require('cors');
const mongoose = require('mongoose');
require('dotenv').config(); // For .env file

const app = express();
const port = process.env.PORT || 5000;
app.use(cors);
app.use(express.json());

const uri = process.env.ATLAS_URI;

mongoose.connect(uri, { useNewUrlParser: true, useCreateIndex: true });
const connection = mongoose.connection;
connection.once('open', () => {
  console.log("MongoDB database connection established successfully");
})

const exercisesRouter = require('./routes/exercises');
const usersRouter = require('./routes/users');
app.use('/exercises',exercisesRouter);
app.use('/users',usersRouter);

app.listen(port, () => {
    console.log(`Server is running on Port: ${port}`);
});
```

The **users.js** code in the routes directory:

```
const router = require('express').Router();
let User = require('../models/user.model');
router.route('/').get((req,res) => {
    User.find() // 
        .then(users => res.json(users))
        .catch(err => res.status(400).json('Error: ' + err));
});

router.route('/add').post((req,res) => {
    const username = req.body.username;
    const newUser = new User({username});
    newUser.save()
        .then(() => res.json('User added!'))
        .catch(err => res.status(400).json('Error: ' + err));
        
});
module.exports = router;
```

The User Model: **user.model.js**

```
const mongoose = require('mongoose');
const Schema = mongoose.Schema;
const userSchema = new Schema({
        username: {
            type: String,
            required: true,
            unique: true,
            trim: true,
            minlength: 3
        },
    },{
        timestamps: true,
});
const User = mongoose.model('User',userSchema);
module.exports = User;
```

The API request which I was sending:

```
curl --location --request POST 'http://localhost:5000/users/add' \
--header 'Content: application/json' \
--header 'Content-Type: application/json' \
--data-raw '{
    "username":"anything"
}'
```

I am not sure what is going wrong, but I don't get a response from the server as such. I used POSTMAN as well for this but no response. 
The blog for reference: https://medium.com/@beaucarnes/learn-the-mern-stack-by-building-an-exercise-tracker-mern-tutorial-59c13c1237a1 
PS: I am a newbie in NodeJS henceforth the weird confusion. Thanks for your time!

The Github Link:- https://github.com/sparsh2706/mern-exerciese-tracker

Edit: Also checked the Postman Console Log and found it gave the error "**Socket Hang up**"

Comment: Can you share code on git or in any other format?

Comment: Put some console logs and debug. You will know where its getting stuck..........

Comment: @Vickrant I did put a console log at the start of the /users/add route but it didn't print out anything as such. So my wild guess is that the request is not even reaching the server.

Comment: @adeel the github link: [link](https://github.com/sparsh2706/mern-exerciese-tracker)

Answer (score 0):

One thing to check if there is a timeout/socket hangup is to check if the MongoDB connection was successful or not.

```
mongoose
  .connect(uri, { useNewUrlParser: true, useCreateIndex: true })
  .then(() => {
    console.log("connection sucess");
  })
  .catch((e) => {
    console.log(e);
    console.log("connection failed");
  });
```

Add CORS rule

```
app.use(cors({ origin: "*", optionsSuccessStatus: 200 }));
```

Try the same request via postman/insomnia.

Comment: The MongoDB connection was successful as is displayed in the console.

Comment: can you try with connection.on instead of connection.once

Comment: I sent the request with Postman too with connection.on: https://ibb.co/yFYGpdW (Screenshot)

Also, I have updated a github link in the question should you need it. Thanks!

Comment: I tried the code in GitHub I can see that DB connection failed

Comment: I have found 2 issues one with the CORS rule and DB connection. I tried with local MongoDB and with the updated CORS rule I am getting a response "User added!".

Comment: Ok i'll try with my local MongoDB then! Thanks

Comment: I added the CORS rule above and also changed the URL to my local MongoDB: 'mongodb://localhost:27017/learn', it did show the connection is established successfully but still I didn't get any response. DId you change anything else in the code?

Comment: The updated Code screenshot: https://ibb.co/8B0X7KK  [LOCAL_URI = 'mongodb://localhost:27017/learn'] in the above screenshot.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/225783/discussion-between-sparsh-dutta-and-jithin-zachariah).